# "...easy enough, except..." Is this correct?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I heard this line in the movie "The social network". The full line is:

> The truth is she has a nice face. I need to do something to take my mind off her. Easy enough, **except I need an idea**.

What I know is that the meaning of the word "except" means "not including" or "other than". I am sure he is not saying "something except an idea". How does this line make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Easy enough* refers back to *do something to take my mind off her*. The latter describes the degree of difficulty in performing the former; it means it will be *fairly easy or simple to occupy my mind and avoid thinking about her if I am doing something else*.

In this case, *except* means *but* or *except for the fact that*. Once he gets an idea, it will be easy. But until that happens, it is not.

Answer (score 2):

In this case **except** functions as a conjunction, namely only, [see definition #1](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/except) from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language.

So, the sentence reads:

> Easy enough, only I need an idea.